# Sails 10.x waterline: What attribute type to use for Mongo objectID

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

sailsjs: I am trying to define a model. I would like to add a property vendorID. The type would be the monogdb objectID from the vendor collection.
Something like for a store model:
`module.exports ={
 attributes :{ 
    vendorId : { type: <Monog ObjectId>},  <-- this would be a FK to the vendor Collection
    storeName: {type: 'string'}
    ....
}`

Waterline docu says:

The following attribute types are currently available:

- string
- text
- integer
- float
- date
- time
- datetime
- boolean
- binary
- array
- json

So what do I pick?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into SailsJS [associations](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations). With waterline you shouldn't need to deal directly with `id` types. Just create an attribute that points to another collection via the `model` or `collection` properties.

Here's a simple example from the Sails/Waterline docs.

```
//Pet.js - A Pet may only have a single user
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name:'STRING',
        color:'STRING',
        owner:{
            model:'user'
        }
    }

}

//User.js - A user may have multiple pets
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name:'STRING',
        age:'INTEGER',
        pets:{
            collection: 'pet',
            via: 'owner'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: that works. I noticed the ObjectID gets converted into a string in waterline. So I can use the string as reference in other collections too.

Answer (score 0):

The _id is created automatically for you by Waterline you don't have to do this.